# Move elements using array_chunk with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, chunks

I have a basic array in which I am using array_chunk to divide it into 3 elements.

```
$array = array(
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'
);

$chunk = array_chunk($array, 3);
```

The result is as follows

```
[
   [
     "a",
     "b",
     "c"
   ],
   [
     "d",
     "e",
     "f"
   ],
   [
     "g",
     "h"
   ]
]
```

(Las chunk have 2 elements)

In case the last "chunk" has only 2 elements, how can I move down an element of the first chunk so that the first element has 2?

It should look like this:

```
[
   [
     "a",
     "b",
   ],
   [
     "c"
     "d",
     "e",
   ],
   [
     "f"
     "g",
     "h
   ]
]
```

(First chunk have 2 elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way are mutliple executions of erray_reverse: first reverse the entire array, then split, then reverse every chunk and then, lastly, the array of chunks.

As a one-liner, it loooks like this: `$chunk = array_reverse(array_map('array_reverse', array_chunk(array_reverse($array), 3)));`

Mind however that reversing an array is an expensive operation, so if you array is acutally alrger than in your example, this is not a recommended way.

---

More effective but also more code:
Calculate the number of elements need to be in the first chunk using modulo:
`$first_chunk_size = count($array) % 3;`

Next, to avoid an empty array if array size is a multiple of chunk size, correct the chunk size if modulo yields 0:
`$first_chunk_size = $first_chunk_size == 0 ? 3 : $first_chunk_size;`

then, cut off the first part:
`$first_chunk = array_slice($array, 0, $first_chunk_size);`

next, split the rest of the array:
`$chunks = array_chunk(array_slice($array,$first_chunk_size),3);`

then combine the first chunk and the other chunks into one array:
`array_unshift($chunks, $first_chunk);`

Full code of the second approach:

```
$array = [
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'
];

$first_chunk_size = count($array) % 3;
$first_chunk_size = $first_chunk_size == 0 ? 3 : $first_chunk_size;

$first_chunk = array_slice($array, 0, $first_chunk_size);
$chunks = array_chunk(array_slice($array,$first_chunk_size),3);
array_unshift($chunks, $first_chunk);

var_dump($chunks);
```

(obviously this code can be simplified by not doing everything step-by-step)

---

**EDIT:** Having read your comments to the other replies, you can modify this approach a little and turn it into a recusrive function. With some code-cleanup,. it may look like this:

```
$array = [
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'
];

function custom_array_chunk ($array) {
    $first_chunk_size = count($array) % 3;
    if ($first_chunk_size == 0) {
        $chunks = array_chunk($array, 3);
    } else {
        $chunks = custom_array_chunk(array_slice($array,2));
        array_unshift($chunks, array_slice($array, 0, 2));
    }
    return $chunks;
}

var_dump(custom_array_chunk($array));
```

This will work for both cases, 1 and 2 elements "left over" and will yield exactly what you told us.

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/94345d85df3558d233a93eed14a5ecc908fb6e29)

Comment: You don't need to calculate `$chunk_elements`, because `count($array) % 3` will return what you need.

Comment: Waait, nevermind. I understood your comment. You are correct.

Comment: Edited accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I do not speak any spanish.

Comment: Either waym @CristianMeza, see my edit in the reply above.

Comment: Edit: Thanks for your detailed response. The array can return 1, 2 or 3 elements. If I return 2, I move the last element of the first chunk down (question of the thread), but in case the last chunk returns only 1 element, as I can leave the first chunk with 1 element, get the first element of the second chunk and leave both the first and the second chunk with 2 elements? I know it costs a bit to understand it, but the result would be the following: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1abf11ce7243e5de7dc16e3809322943e0205f34 Cheerz

Comment: It has worked perfectly for me. Very grateful for your help @JohannesH. Cheerz

Answer (score 1):

You could reverse you array first using [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php), then use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php). Then reverse the inner arrays, and reverse the outer arrays again:

```
$array = array(
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
    'd',
    'e',
    'f',
    'g',
    'h'
);
$array = array_reverse($array);
$chunk = array_chunk($array, 3);
$array = array_map('array_reverse', $chunk);
print_r(array_reverse($array));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/STZFf)

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => d
            [2] => e
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => f
            [1] => g
            [2] => h
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have another question, in case the last row of the chunk has only 1 element, how can I take only 1 element (last element) of the first row and move it down? Thanks

Comment: @CristianMeza it sounds you want to combine the two chunks if there is a chunk with only a single element? That sounds like a separate question to me.

Comment: @cmbuckley I think he actually wants to have a minimum number of 2 elements in the first chunk and the last chunk, preferring the last chunk to have 3 over the first. See my reply for a solution.

Comment: @CristianMeza Not really sure what you mean. That sounds like a different question. Something like: https://3v4l.org/8U52a

Comment: @CristianMeza Rather than us guessing, if you post a different question with expected output, that's the easiest way to get the best answer.

Comment: The following can happen:

The last chunk of the array can return 1, 2 or 3 elements. If I return 2, I move the last element of the first chunk down (question of the thread), but in case the last chunk returns only 1 element, as I can leave the first chunk with 1 element, get the first element of the second chunk and leave both the first and the second chunk with 2 elements? I know it costs a bit to understand it, but the result would be the following:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1abf11ce7243e5de7dc16e3809322943e0205f34

Comment: @CristianMeza See my change Edit in my reply.

Answer (score 1):

Functionally, the multiple array_reverse approach is quite understandable:

```
$chunk = array_reverse(array_map('array_reverse', array_chunk(array_reverse($array), 3)));
```

However, it's quite expensive, especially for larger arrays. Another way is to slice elements off the end of the array and prepend them to your chunked array:

```
$size = 3;
$chunk = array();
while (count($array) > 0) {
    array_unshift($chunk, array_slice($array, -$size));
    $array = array_slice($array, 0, -$size);
}
```

This works out about 20 times faster (over 100k iterations) for your array, and is about 1000 times faster for an array containing 600+ items.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend empty datas to your array, in sort of array_chunk be compliant to your need.

Then remove these prepended datas.

```
$chunk = 3;
$nbToPrepend = ($chunk - count($array) % $chunk);
$prepend = array_fill(0, $nbToPrepend, null);
$result = array_chunk(array_merge($prepend, $array), $chunk);
$result[0] = array_slice($result[0], $nbToPrepend);
```